# All objects are completely black in material preview

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, 3d-view

I've been using Blender for a couple of years on my mac but I completely skipped over the basics and how to actually work things.

That being said, I was working on a project, saved my file, closed Blender, and the next time I opened it the material preview was entirely black. (excluding the background and the floor).

[image: Text]

I have no idea why this happened, I didn't touch any of the settings, at least not on purpose. It's not the lighting or the materials being metallic because the viewport worked perfectly fine before. The render viewport wasn't affected at all either.

[image: Text]
Please help.

Comment: Click the little arrow in the bottom right next to the viewport preview selection "circles" and see if checking/unchecking "scene lights" and/or "scene world" fixes it.

Comment: your image links are broken, can u add new images?

Comment: @ChristopherBennett But that would not explain why his floor plane is visible (though in a very 2d way that looks like a grease pencil drawing). And (to the OP) please attach your .blend file if it's possible.